# Refinement panel not working in sharepoint 2013

Tags: search-results

I have http site and https(anonymous site), I have implemented the search, the search working fine in http site. But in https site, the search results web part showing the results but the refinement panel web part didn't showing the results. What could be the issue?

Comment: Having the same issue :(
If someone has a solution please drop a note

Comment: Please donot post your questions/requests in the answer section, kindly follow as mentioned in the following URL http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer